# Mysql query error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I try to use a query about finding users around with this query:

```
                Select id, username, lat, long,
                    acos(sin(0.761312289853)*sin(radians(lat)) + cos(0.761312289853)*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(long)-0.0676354285243)) * 6371 As D
                From (
                    Select id, username, lat, long,
                    From rcp_users
                    Where lat Between 43.4491099949 And 43.7908522051
                      And long Between 3.63919239657 And 4.11125680343
                ) As FirstCut
                Where acos(sin(0.761312289853)*sin(radians(lat)) + cos(0.761312289853)*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(long)-0.0676354285243)) * 6371 < 30
                Order by D
```

but I have this error:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'long,
                    acos(sin(0.761312289853)*sin(radians(lat)) + cos(0.761312289853)*' at line 1
```

I don't understand the error..

Comment: may be use backtick for long ?

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? If the concept of reserved keywords unknown to you, this is a very weird error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`long` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html). If you're going to name a column identifier that you *must* wrap it in ticks:

```
Select id, username, lat, `long`,
    acos(sin(0.761312289853)*sin(radians(lat)) + cos(0.761312289853)*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(`long`)-0.0676354285243)) * 6371 As D
From (
    Select id, username, lat, `long`,
    From rcp_users
    Where lat Between 43.4491099949 And 43.7908522051
      And `long` Between 3.63919239657 And 4.11125680343
) As FirstCut
Where acos(sin(0.761312289853)*sin(radians(lat)) + cos(0.761312289853)*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(`long`)-0.0676354285243)) * 6371 < 19
Order by D
```

Comment: Make sure you correct every instance where `long` is used. I see I missed one as @GordonLinoff was kind enough to correct.

Comment: Haven't seen that reserved used in a question for a while.

Comment: Yeah, it is not one of the common ones. But I guess they all get (mis)used at some point.

Answer (score 0):

`long` is an [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html), you're not allowed to use iut like that because it has another meaning in mysql.

You can use it by using backticks (like the single quotes in php make things litteral):

```
SELECT id, username, lat, `long` FROM table
```

To make it a bit more obvious, say you have a column in your database called `select`:

```
SELECT id,username,select FROM table // this will not work, select is reserved
```

Comment: Why the downvote? What can be so wrong in these few lines it's worthy of a downvote?